# SharePoint 2010 MasterPage Footer - Custom Table

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

Good Morning,

Little bit of help f possible. I have customised my SharePoint masterpage with a footer. This footer has a table in it which is split up into columns.

Within one of the columns I have added 3 custom search boxes, a sharepoint 2010 hit counter webpart and some text and a logo.

However when I publish this page not all of these elements are displayed. I know the page loads them as I can see them when I view the source code for the page so I am guessing they are hiding under the first element.

Enclosed is the code I am using within this table. If anyone is able to offer some advice I would be graetful.

```
<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
      <div>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 22px">

<form action="http://bbmmtoday.bbmmjv.com/_layouts/searchresults.aspx">
    <input type=text name=k placeholder="enter search..." size="32" id=k class="search"><input type="submit" value="search" class="button" >
        </form></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>

&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

        <td>

<form action="http://bbmmtoday.bbmmjv.com/_layouts/searchresults.aspx">
    <input type=text name=k placeholder="enter search..." size="32" id=k class="search"><input type="submit" value="search" class="button" >
        </form></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>

        <td>

&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <td>

<form action="http://bbmmtoday.bbmmjv.com/_layouts/searchresults.aspx">
    <input type=text name=k placeholder="enter search..." size="32" id=k class="search"><input type="submit" value="search" class="button" >
        </form></td>

      </div>
      <tr>
<td>

&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
<td>

&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
<td>

&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
<td>

                      <span lang="en-gb">
<AEPageHitsWebpart:AEPageHits runat="server" Description="Displays the page hit count of the current page" Options="" Title="AE Page Hits Web Part" ImportErrorMessage="Cannot import the AE Page Hits Web Part." IsActive="True" SinceDate="10/11/2014 10:00:00" ChromeType="TitleAndBorder" Template="&lt;div style=&quot;height: 20px; width:200px;background-color:#fead30; Segoe UI;font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; color:#2e3e3f;padding:6px&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;{hits}&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; Page hits since {since}&lt;br&gt;" ID="g_a2b9d6ba_62b2_41b5_8536_21e1972eab00" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{a2b9d6ba-62b2-41b5-8536-21e1972eab00}" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __designer:IsClosed="false"></AEPageHitsWebpart:AEPageHits></span>

        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
                                &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
                                <span lang="en-gb">&nbsp;Created by <strong>
                                <a href="mailto:%20ray.spiteri@bbmmjv.com" class="style4">Ray 
                                Spiteri</a></strong> and <strong>
                                <a href="mailto:%20tim.quadling@bbmmjv.com" class="style4">Tim Quadling</a></strong></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
                                &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">

                        <img alt="" valign="bottom" align="left" src="http://bbmmtoday.bbmmjv.com/SiteAssets/bbmm%20logo.png" width="286" height="26" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
<AEPageHitsWebpart:AEPageHits runat="server" Description="Displays the page hit count of the current page" Options="" Title="AE Page Hits Web Part" ImportErrorMessage="Cannot import the AE Page Hits Web Part." IsActive="False" SinceDate="10/11/2014 09:00:00" ChromeType="None" Template="Page Hits: {hits}" ID="g_5e6becd0_a22c_4549_8b43_f9a7c860a639" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{5e6becd0-a22c-4549-8b43-f9a7c860a639}" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __designer:IsClosed="false"></AEPageHitsWebpart:AEPageHits></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three suspicious things in your HTML:

- element after the  element with ending  between
- and  Unpair  and
- Two  elements in the end while only 1 opening

All these HTML errors mean that it's on browser how it is rendered. And mostly it's rendered "wrong". Because it's incorrect.